# How to redirect from http to https but no redirect if index.php file in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using this code in htaccess to redirect from http to https. I want no redirect if index.php file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

How I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just tweak your patter in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

`^(index\.php)?$` will match anything but landing page and `index.php`.

Comment: Internal server error. Dosnt work. I copy this code from your answer and paste.

Comment: Thank you. Now its work fine. But I want only file example.php . But landing page must redirect to https

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment about `example.php`. This answer is as per your question's requirement that except for `index.php` it redirects `http->https`

Comment: Another question: Redirect all with landing page to https but file example.php.

Comment: Then it would be: `RewriteRule !^example\.php$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]`